# Plotly js and parallel coordinates plots

Tags: javascript, d3.js, plot, plotly

I'm struggling to develop a parallel plot with Plotly js.

I cannot find anything similar among the [example plots](https://plot.ly/javascript/#basic-charts) provided  in the web site. 
Basically I'd like to have the same result as this [example](https://bl.ocks.org/jasondavies/1341281) developed in D3. 
Does anyone know how to do it, already did it before, or has to suggest me something to see?

I can use D3 but using plotly would be better

Any help would be appreciated, thank you very much

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Parallel Plot has been recently added in Plotly. [Here](https://plot.ly/javascript/parallel-coordinates-plot/) you can find some examples.